# Making a back up of database while my application set up

Tags: c#, winforms

i have build up a application in c# for my client.During the testing of the application the client inserts data for testing and whenever i reinstall the updated software the data inserted by the client is replaced by new database.so how can i not replace that database.

Comment: It's not very clear from your question what you are asking.  I get the essence that you want to know how to handle test data, but there are not enough specifics about your situation to give a meaningful answer.  Try rewording it.

Comment: For eg: Games.The data is not lost even if we uninstall the game..Rather we can get it if we re install the same game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

everytime you install the application,you can backup the data into file,and then restore it.